# splitting a braces grouped string in python

Tags: python, string, split

Appreciate help in a one-liner idiom to do the following efficiently.

I have a string with groups separated by braces as below:

```
{1:xxxx}{2:xxxx}{3:{10:xxxx}}{4:xxxx\r\n:xxxx}....
```

How do I convert this into a dictionary format?

```
dict={1:'xxx',2:'xxxx',3:'{10:xxxx}'},4:'xxxx\r\n:xxxx'}
```

Comment: Do the `xxxx`s ever contain braces?

Comment: Good question.They do - and have edited the question like-wise

Comment: Are the "values" randomly quoted/unquoted?

Comment: Are there ever `}{` pairs inside of `xxxx`?

Comment: Are there ever `:` characters inside of `xxxx`? The contents of `xxxx` matter a lot for how to approach this. You could get away with something very simple if these bits are guaranteed not to have certain features.

Comment: Now I have gone to include all the possible used-cases in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
raw = """{1:xxxx}{2:xxxx}{3:{10:xxxx}}{4:'xxxx\r\n:xxxx'}"""

def parse(raw):
    # split into chunks by '}{' and remove the outer '{}'
    parts = raw[1:-1].split('}{')
    for part in parts:
        # split by the first ':'
        num, data = part.split(':', 1)
        # yield each entry found
        yield int(num), data

# make a dict from it
print dict(parse(raw))
```

It keeps the `'{10:xxxx}'` as a string just like in your example.

Answer (score 4):

```
r = """(?x)
{
    (\w+)
    :
    (
        (?:
            [^{}]
            |
            {.+?}
        )+
    )
}
"""

z = "{1:xxxx}{2:xxxx}{3:{10:xxxx}}{4:'xxxx'}"
print dict(re.findall(r, z))

# {'1': 'xxxx', '3': '{10:xxxx}', '2': 'xxxx', '4': "'xxxx'"}
```

Feel free to convert to an one-liner if you want - just remove `(?x)` and all whitespace from the regex.

The above parses only one level of nesting, to handle arbitrary depths consider the more advanced [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module that supports recursive patterns:

```
import regex

r = """(?x)
{
    (\w+)
    :
    (
        (?:
            [^{}]
            |
            (?R)
        )+
    )
}
"""

z = "{1:abc}{2:{3:{4:foo}}}{5:bar}"
print dict(regex.findall(r, z))

# {'1': 'abc', '2': '{3:{4:foo}}', '5': 'bar'}
```

Comment: I like this, but it will fail if there are nested `{}`s in the input string, such as `{3:{10:{}}}` - you'll get back `[('3', '{10:{}')]`.